# What kind of camper do I have?

Tags: camping, manmade-object-identification

I bought some land last December, and it came with a camper.  It's in much better shape than I had feared, but I suspect I'll need a few replacement parts.
How can I figure out which model of Prowler it is?
[image: Camper]
[image: Prowler]

Comment: Do you intend to move it? If the spare parts you need are only for the interior (e.g. the heater) then you'd better off looking for the vendor of that particular heater than the vendor of the whole camper.

Comment: True ... but the roof is shot, and I have no idea if that's repairable/replaceable or not

Comment: Have you considered asking the current manufacturer? I believe this is it: https://heartlandrvs.com/brand/prowler/

Comment: Most trailer/rv parts are replaceable with common off-the-shelf generic replacements; no need to get them from the original manufacturer. As for the roof, you won't be able to get replacement OEM materials. Rather, you should start researching the many options available for RV roof restoration (e.g., elastomeric brush/roll/spray-on coatings, silicone sealers, edpm sheet rubber, etc.); if you intend to do it yourself the first step is to educate yourself. Or just hire it done at an RV shop; might cost more than the value of the coach though...

Answer (score 4):

I'll try with some suggestions. Apparently, the former owner has already had problems with the roof, as he covered it under some sheets. Uncover it completely and try to find out how big the holes or leaks are. The heavy stones now on the roof and the fact that the cover prevents water from getting away might even have worsened the situation. Also try to figure out what the roof is made of. That will tell you who you could ask for help.

- If the roof is made of a metalic plate (such as aluminum), ask in a car repair shop. They should know how to weld in a piece of new cover.
- But more likely, it is made of GRP (glass reinforced plastic). That's the same stuff most modern pleasure boats are made of. It's usually water-tight for a lifetime, except where it's holed (e.g. by bolts or other attachments). To get that repaired, ask in a nearby boatyard. They know how to repair leakages in GRP.

Now, both of these options are obviously not free, how much you can do yourself will depend on your DIY-skills. Welding aluminum is very difficult and requires the right tools, and working with GRP and epoxy (a glue) is rather a mess.